# RewriteCond variable back-referencing of %2

Tags: mod-rewrite

this is htaccess file on the server

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]+)\.domain.com(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/test\.php?user=%1&path=%2 [R]
```

According to my understanding of the above code if i request **asher.domain.com/user** it should rewrite to **http://domain.com/test.php?user=asher&path=/user** right?

Instead i get **http://domain.com/test.php?user=asher&path=** The **%2** is empty. but if i use **$1** instead of **%2** i seem to get the right result.

I might be doing the silliest mistake ever but I am not sure where I my mistake is. Help me out here guys? where is the mistake in the rewrite rules that %2 is not working for me?

Comment: In second RewriteCond,  I suspect the dot between domain and com needs to be escaped, by backslash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `$` syntax gives you `RewriteRule` backreferences, while the `%` will give you `RewriteCond` backreferences.  The [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) documentation covers this.

In your case, your `RewriteRule` should look like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/test\.php?user=%1&path=$1 [R]
```

Because you want the first group match from the previous `RewriteCond` and the first group match from the current `RewriteRule`.

Comment: oh. i was expecting '(.*)' in the second 'RewriteCond' would match to %2. is this not the case here?

Comment: It does, but `${HTTP_HOST}` won't have anything in it passed the `.com`.  It's just the hostname, it doesn't contain the request URI.